# PC turns off in 30 sec -1 min

Tags: desktop-computer

I have a gigabyte motherboard 2 GB ram memory an iBall power supply unit dual core CPU and a Seagate hard disk.

The entire assembly has been working well for the past 9 years on an iBall cabinet.

For a past few months the computer turned off several times all of a sudden without any warnings like the mains were pulled off from the wall.

This became regular as the PC worked not more than 15 to 30 mins For normal operations.

I decided to thoroughly clean the entire assembly hoping that helps.

This included brushing the CPU heat sink entire motherboard including the base, front panel connections and insides of PSU including the fans.

I got the PSU tested from a local shop and it runs fine. There was left over dried out thermal paste on the heat sink plate which is left as it is and doesn't look like any capacitors of the mob is visually leaking.

I did an experiment unplugging everything turning on the pc just with PSU cable to the mob. The fan of both CPU and PSU runs well for exactly 30 secs as usual and then every thing shuts off.

What is the problem?

Comment: It sounds like a flaky PSU. Some PSU problems are difficult to detect. Swapping the PSU is sometimes the only way to confirm or rule out a PSU problem. Perhaps your local shop has a spare you can try.

Comment: No good way to test a PSU reliably.

Comment: @Moab You write "No good way to test a PSU reliably"  <-- actually, you can backprove it with a volt/multimeter and if the results come up bad you know it is bad, otherwise it's unknown.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply ill check with an alternate psu from the nearby shop I also want the psu to be faulty as it's the cheapest

Comment: @barlop, still there is no good way to test for 100% reliability, well you can but is cost prohibitive.

Comment: @Moab yeah you can't test for 100% reliability - though nothing is 100% reliable so even that is a funny/'misleading' thing to say re no tests for it., But you said there is no good way to test a PSU reliably, and there are tests whose results are 100% reliable! e.g. if a PSU fails a test you can know it's not good!

Comment: Reliably means 100%, not misleading at all.